# Laravel API Conditional Relationship

Tags: laravel

I am building a Laravel Application where people read book, favorite the  book also.

**Book Resource**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
   // return parent::toArray($request);
   return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'about' => $this->about,
        'content' => $this->content,
        'image' => $this->image_url,
        'recommended' => $this->recommended,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'author' => $this->author,
        'no_of_pages' => $this->pages,
   //    'favorited' =>  I want o show true or false depending if user favorited 
   ];
}
```

I want to set include Favorited Book by the user in the user model, so it shows true if the user has favorited and false.

I was able to do it in a single book model, by doing this

```
public function showapi(Request $request, $book)
{

    //$book = Book::find($book);
    $book  = new BookResource(Book::find($book));
    $Fav = Favorite::where('book_id', $book->id)->where('user_id', $request->user_id)->exists();
    if($Fav) {
    return response()->json([
        'book' => $book, 
        'Favorited' => $Fav,
        ]
    );
  }
  else 
  return response()->json([
    'book' => $book, 
    'Favorited' => $Fav,
    ]
);
```

}

This set Favorited to True or False

**But I want to show Favorited when I send the collection of Books**

**I have tried using Laravel API Resource Relationship by doing this**

```
    'item' => FavoriteResource::collection($this->when(Favorite::where('book_id', $this->id)
->where('user_id', $request->user_id), 'item')),
```

I got this error while using postman to test

> Call to a member function first() on string in file

This is my method

```
public function indexapi()
{
  return BookResource::collection(Book::with('author')->Paginate(16));
}
```

This is my relationship

**User Model**

```
public function favorites(){
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}

public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}
```

**Book Model**

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
```

** Favorite Model **

```
public function book ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}

public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Whats the relationship between user and books? Is it many to many?

Comment: There is no relationship between user and books. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is solution to your problem, but just want to edit your model as you missed a part in the book model

**User model**

```
    public function favorites(){
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}

public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}
```

**Book Model**

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
public function User()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

**Your favourited class**

```
 public function book ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}

public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: sorry for that little error on books model, have edited it

Answer (score 0):

You have a many to many relationship between your books and your users. The pairs are stored in the intermediate table `book_user`. Just add a boolean column `favorite` to the intermediate table `book_user`.

You may access it like this:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->books as $book) {
    echo $book->pivot->favorite;
}
```

Read more about the intermediate table [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

You may also want to create a model representing the [intermediate table](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) (this would be your favorite model).