# Looping all Data in Laravel API Response

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an API, in the book model, I want give a response which will contain the book and the favorite status of the book. If the authenticated user favorited the book, it should be true else it should be false. This is the code I came up with, but this code only loop once. Its there a method where I can loop all the books in the response?

```
public function indexapi(Request $request)
    {
    $books = BookResource::collection(Book::with('author')->Paginate(16));
    $count = Book::with('author')->count();
    $Fav = Favorite::where('book_id', $request->book_id)->where('user_id', $request->user_id)->exists();
      foreach($books as $key => $book) {
            return response()->json([
          'book' => $book, 
          'Favorited' => $Fav,
          ]
      );  
    }
```

> I am trying to loop book and favorite into in my API response to get responses like this

```
{
    "book": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "4.50 from Paddington",
        "author": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Agatha Christie",
        },
    },

    "Favorited": false
}

{
    "book": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "4.50 from Paddington",
        "author": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Agatha Christie",
        },
    },

    "Favorited": false
}

{
    "book": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "4.50 from Paddington",
        "author": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Agatha Christie",
        },
    },

    "Favorited": true
}
```

I am stuck in this

I have tried to use 'while loop' and 'foreach' together.

Comment: "but this code only loop once." cause you are returning in for-each - try to put them into a temporary array, collection etc and then return please.

Comment: @ersoy How do I  do this please

Comment: before foreach just create an $array = []; and push them in foreach, then return that array. Because you are returning your first iteration of foreach by using "return" inside it.

Answer (score 1):

It is only looping once because it will encounter the return statement and when it does,  the loop will stop its execution, try this as i did not test it and see if it works for you

```
 public function indexapi(Request $request)
    {
    $books = BookResource::collection(Book::with('author')->Paginate(16));
    $count = Book::with('author')->count();
    $Fav = Favorite::where('book_id', $request->book_id)->where('user_id', 

$request->user_id)->exists();
$books_array=[];

      foreach($books as $key => $book) {
//this is if you are pushing without key
array_push($books_array,$book);
//now with keys
$books_array['books']=$book;
$books_array['favourited']=$fav;
      );  
/*for efficiency, you can add the favourited outside the loop and delete it in the loop and it will look like this */
$books_array['favourited']=$fav;
return response()->json(['books'=>$books_array]);
          );


    }
```

Comment: It returned this error  "message": "Call to a member function push() on array",

Comment: sorry for the misuse of that function, i will rewrite it now

Comment: try the edited one, i forgot this is php and not javascript

Comment: i forgot the fav, just added it now

Comment: Please one more thing, for efficiency, rather than adding the favourite in the loop, you can add it after the loop, i make an edit to show you

Comment: It didn't work. It only returned fav for only one book, other books no fav

Comment: you can't loop over those two, what you have to do is to use relationship, and then loop over them

Comment: You're right, the only this can be solve is through relationship between the models. I have been trying to use relationship to solve but I couldn't. I have asked the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026742/laravel-api-conditional-relationship. But I didn't get a proper answer

Comment: i will look into it